# Page renders with me having upvoted and downvoted simultaneously

Tags: bug, voting

I think it's easiest to just explain this with a picture and steps to reproduce:

[image]

1. Downvote a post. Leave that tab open.
2. Wait for the post to get edited.
3. Open a new tab and upvote that post.
4. Wait for the original tab to say that the post has been edited and use that link to reload the post.
5. Observe. The hover text for both says "click to undo". The vote count is off (it should read 2 in the screenshot). It also doesn't show the accept check mark, which it should.

This is pretty obviously an edge case, but it's definitely confusing and unintuitive. I don't know if it's worth fixing, but I figured I'd report it anyway.

Comment: Chrome version 18.0.1025.162 m on Windows 7, in case that's relevant.

Comment: Hmm couldn't reproduce (with this thread). Must not work on edits you make.